# Why am i getting this error when i am trying to insert a string into a list?

Tags: python, list, insert

i am running the following code.

```
a = ["hello","bye","where","am","i"]
ls_capitalize = [x.capitalize() for x in a]
reverse = reversed(ls_capitalize)
reverse.insert(2,"Extra")
print(reverse,"\n",ls_capitalize )
```

I am trying to insert a string in the list after reversing it and i am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 4, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list_reverseiterator' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

If `insert()` is not working for this what could i use?

Comment: It's just as the error says - `reversed` function returns an iterator, therefore a correct way to re-write the third line would be `reverse = [i for i in reversed(ls_capitalize)]`. And then it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `reversed` doesn't return a list, it returns an iterator.  That's why it says `list_reverseiterator` doesn't have `insert`.  Try

```
a = ["hello","bye","where","am","i"]
ls_capitalize = [x.capitalize() for x in a]
reverse = list(reversed(ls_capitalize))
reverse.insert(2,"Extra")
print(reverse,"\n",ls_capitalize )
```

Comment: or even better: use `ls_capitalize = [x.capitalize() for x in a[::-1]]` to avoid reversing altogether

Comment: @asdfCYBER He ends up using both `ls_capitalize` and `reverse` separately, so he needs both lists.  Though I'm sure there are some better ways to do it.